# Catch DllNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, exception, dll

I'm not a 100% sure what's happening, but I think that's what's going on: I use a third party dll in my C# project to access a hardware device. To do so I added 2 dlls to the project's references (Description: .net Interface; Copy Local: False) and use them in my class using the using-statement. 
All of this works well as long as drivers for the hardware device are installed. On a computer where those are not installed the application dies as soon as I try to access the relevant class.

What are the necessary steps to catch those exceptions or how can I prevent calling those methods that require a dll that's not found? I've tried to catch the exception but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you "use" that 3rd party DLL in your project ? Is that a C dll ?

Comment: ` I've tried to catch the exception but that didn't work.` does this mean you did-t get somthing like "class not foud exceptionj"? can you post example code.

Comment: The exception is thrown *early*, happens when the jitter needs to produce the code for the method.  So you surely have the try/catch in the wrong place.  You need to use Assembly.Load() to have a guarantee that you can always reliably detect a missing assembly.  Or just don't bother if your program is not useful without it.