# Catch DllNotFoundException not working with Phidget API

Tags: c#, dllnotfoundexception, phidgets

I need to reference a dll to instantiate an object. There are cases where the dll will not exist because the Phidget drivers are not installed on those systems. In those cases I just want to catch the `DllNotFoundException`, but it's not working. I even tried nesting catch statements between the type reference and the instantiation, but still not catching. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `catch (System.DllNotFoundException)`? I know it shouldn't make a difference if you have a `using System;` statement but all the google results I've found specifically use the full namespace in the `catch` statement.

Comment: Also have you tried just `catch (Exception ex)` to see if it catches it then?

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes I tried both suggestions but same result.

Comment: Huh, seems to work here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kN0V5J. I would try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to clean solution and then rebuild solution.

Comment: @LewsTherin I think the issue is that the exception is being thrown within the dll and it's not bubbling up. I believe that my referenced dll internally references another dll on the system. If that system dll is not installed, it throws the exception. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just found this, which is the same problem I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785259/catch-dllnotfound-exception?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing a problem very similar to [Why does short-circuiting not prevent MissingMethodException related to unreachable branch of logical AND (&&)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5233155/103167)

Put the catch in a separate function, one that does not use `typeof(Phidget22.DigitalInput)` or any other identifier from the DLL.

Exceptions such as `TypeLoadException`, `MissingMethodException`, and `DllNoFoundException` can be called by the JIT compiler before execution of your function starts (and then catch blocks in the function will have no effect).